# Wkhtml to export pdf with utf-8 tamil language

Tags: php, exec, wkhtmltopdf

In command prompt direct command execution at windows command tamil language is exporting successfully

`wkhtmltopdf.exe --encoding UTF-8 http://localhost/pdfexport/phpwkhtmltopdf-master/page.html file/test.pdf`

But executing same command via PHP `exec($cmd)` tamil strings is not exporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this sounds like PHP was not configured correctly for UTF8 support.
In pure PHP, without exec(), could you verify this `echo "ஆங்கிலம்";` gets printed on screen in a webpage or script of sort?
Do this indepenetly of *wkhtmltopdf*.

Comment: I called ttf font 'Noto Sans Tamil.ttf' in html style now tamil font executing properly with tamil content